# Experiencing lag during games despite meeting system requirements..help please

Tags: memory, graphics-card, performance, cpu, lag

Here are my computer specs

Mainboard: ASRock M3N78D
CPU: AMD Phenom II X4 960T
Video card: GTX 560
RAM: 4G
Hard Disk: Samsung HD501LJ

XCOM Enemy Within recommended requirements

CPU: Core 2 Quad Q6600 2.4GHz / Athlon II X4 620
Video card: GeForce 9600 GT Extreme 512MB / Radeon HD 3870
RAM: 4 GB

The game I am experiencing lag with is XCOM Enemy Within. I am getting about 22 fps and it isn't much of a problem since it's a turn based strategy game, but I think the performance should be better. Lowering the graphic settings changes nothing. I've tried running the game with dx9, and I think the average fps may have improved a bit, but still fell short of 30. CPU usage is at 30%, memory at 66%, temperatures for CPU, GPU are 34 and 50 degrees celcius I think. What do you think is the problem? On a side note, I played Bioshock Infinite and Sniper Elite 3 just fine on the same pc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You sure the game is using the dedicated gpu instead of integrated?

Comment: You don't seen sure about some things we need certainty to help

Answer (score 0):

A simple search will find the cause of this problem.

From [Steam](http://steamcommunity.com/app/200510/discussions/0/648811852356859548/):

> For those of you experiencing this (initially rather annoying) problem, have a look at your 'GPU activity'. It's possible (as in my case) that the DLC is **preset to run using integrated graphics, by default.** Access your GPU setting and manually force 'enemy within EXE' to run using your GPU, as opposed to integrated graphics.

From [another forum](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f59/solved-low-fps-in-xcom-enemy-unknown-804137.html):

> So far Enemy Within does not want to recognize mobile nvidia cards (I havent met anyone with a mobile ATI card yet).

Solution:

1. Go to **Nvidia Control Panel>Manage 3D Settings>Program Settings**
2. Find the application (XCOM Enemy Within) and manually set the game to run using the **Nvidia GPU** rather than your **Integrated Graphics Card**.
3. Save and exit. See [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/175281/how-to-force-graphics-options-in-pc-games-with-nvidia-amd-or-intel-graphics/) if you need more help.

The game should run at at a higher fps now.